# Kinematics in the pion decay

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, pions

If a charged pion decays via a charged current $W$, the $W$ boson is much heavier than the pions. How is this not a problem? Could the processes be off-shell in such a drastic manner?

It is tempting consider the $Z$ or $W$ as virtual particles, however if we were to consider the Drell Yan process, weak interaction only contributes to the scattering cross section at a centre of mass energy above 60 GeV. It seems that there is actually no essential difference, except in the first case we are considering a bound state and in the later case we are dealing with a scattering process.

Comment: Note that the $W$ mass appears in the denominator of the Fermi coupling for weak decays, $G_F\propto M_W^{-2}$.

Comment: The W is virtual, i.e. off mass shell. see this for virtual This link explains it, there is a W and Z paragraph http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html

Comment: ? Have you ever covered muon decay, or any other low energy weak interaction process?

Comment: Yes, I certainly didn’t seriously consider the order of magnitudes involved. Simply felt quite a surprise, such a low energy effect is influenced by such a high energy theory. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course charged pion decays involve the exchange of virtual Ws, like all low-energy weak interactions. As you may have learned in your introductory HEP course, charged pions are the longest-lived hadrons, since, being the lightest, cannot decay strongly, but only weakly, so their decay is *slow*: 2.6 $\cdot 10^{-8}$s.

In natural units, this amounts to
$$
\Gamma_{\pi^{\pm}}\sim 2.5~\cdot 10^{-15}MeV,
$$
as compared to a routine strong decay,
$$
\Gamma_\rho   \sim 150 MeV.
$$

Since the W involved is necessarily virtual, its propagator amounts to a 4th power of $M_W$ in the denominator of the width, so, veeery crudely, from dimensional analysis,
$$
\Gamma_{\pi^{\pm}}\propto \frac{ m_\mu^2(K.E.)^3}{M_W^4} 
$$
within a few orders of magnitude of the above experimental width! (Have used 4MeV for the [kinetic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/piondec.html) of the muon.)

So the comparison to Drell-Yann is inapposite: you never see the suppressed low-energy Drell-Yan process.  But the pion has *no other way to decay*, beyond this freakishly small width channel, suppressed by 17 orders of magnitude w.r.t. its fellow hadrons' strong decays!

Comment: I would just like to add to "cannot decay strongly, only weakly" - they also cannot decay electromagnetically. The neutral pion for example cannot decay strongly; it decays electromagnetically to two photons and it lasts much less time than the charged pion.

Comment: @AXensen Of course. The OP was evidently asking about charged pions. The neutral pion is a gloriously different animal in this respect...